# How to switch UI5 content on demand?

Tags: sapui5

```xml
<semantic:DetailPage title="Detail Page Title">
  <mvc:XMLView viewName="query.sap.view.Table" />
  <mvc:XMLView viewName="query.sap.view.chart" />
</semantic:DetailPage>
```

I have two nested views in the same content and I want to display only one of them. When I press a button, it should switch to the other one.

Comment: Is this button inside the nested view or outside it ?

Comment: try hiding view. Keep visible view which one you want to show when application is launched and hide another one. when you click button hide current one and make visible hidden one. sap.ui.getCore().byId("viewId").setVisible(false) this way or by this.getView().byId("ViewId").setVisible(false).

Comment: When loading views, watch out not to instantiate them all at once. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799046/5846045

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets have a switch and save its current value to a local JSON Model. Now, we will use this value to switch between the 2 views. If switch is true, show first view else show second switch.

Below is the code:

XML (  I've just used the texts in place of View (same thing)) :

```
        <Switch state='{/showFirstView}' />
        <Text text='TExt 1' visible='{/showFirstView}' />
        <Text text='TExt 2' visible='{=!${/showFirstView}}' />
```

Controller:

```
onInit: function() {
        var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({showFirstView:true});
        this.getView().setModel(model);
    },
```

and it works. Screenshots:
[image]

and :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to make only one of the controls visible (in our case one of the child `View`s), one might be tempted to instantiate all controls first and then use the `visible` property to hide the other "unneeded" controls. But keep in mind that this approach might lead to [performance and memory issues](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/966d67c8cc5046419d1b35556cd9e447) depending on the complexity and the number of elements. According to the linked documentation topic:

> ### Don't use visibility for lazy instantiation
>
> When an application has areas that are not visible initially, or if only one of multiple options is visible at a time, do **not** create all UI controls and set most of them to non-visible! If you do, OpenUI5 will instantiate and initialize all of those controls, which consumes unnecessary time and memory, even when they are not rendered. On top of this, the data binding will also be initialized, which may trigger back-end requests that are not needed at this stage. The impact is particularly big when the parts of the UI that are not visible initially are complex or numerous.

Luckily, UI5 has already built-in lazy loading features..

## Switching Views on Demand

### Via `NavContainer` + `Router`

Configure the [`targets`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.routing.Targets#constructor) property inside the *app descriptor* file (manifest.json) accordingly as shown in: [https://embed.plnkr.co/HRSJ44/](https://embed.plnkr.co/HRSJ44/?show=manifest.json,preview:%3Fsap-ui-xx-componentPreload%3Doff)

For this, we need three properties for the target object of the child view:

1. `parent`: Pointing to a parent target name where the parent view is defined
2. `controlId`: The ID of the control in which the child view should be attached.
   In the Plunker example above, the control is a [`NavContainer`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.NavContainer) which also offers a sliding animation as a bonus. The animation can be turned off with `transition: "show"`.
3. `controlAggregation`: In our case `"pages"` (default aggregation of NavContainer).

After defining those three properties, we can either [display the target view without changing the hash](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/d9efab307ecc42b180b12cc8956e22d7), or navigate to the child view by calling `component.getRouter().navTo("thatChildRouteName");`. Either way, the child view will be created lazily and we have a flexible way of switching through different child views.

> [image: UI5 lazy loading on a button press]

### Via "Blocks" (`sap.uxap.BlockBase`)

Views can be loaded lazily and switched also with `sap.uxap.BlockBase` See:

- Example: [https://embed.plnkr.co/9ZVwpP/](https://embed.plnkr.co/9ZVwpP?show=block%2FMyBlock.js,view%2FHome.view.xml,preview:%3Fsap-ui-xx-componentPreload%3Doff)
- Docs:

  - [*Creating Blocks*](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/2978f6064742456ebed31c5ccf4d051d)
  - [*Object Page Blocks*](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/4527729576cb4a4888275b6935aad03a)
  - [API reference: `sap/uxap/BlockBase`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.uxap.BlockBase)

Although Blocks are typically used in conjunction with `sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout` (OPL), they can be also used independently from the OPL design in freestyle apps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a single view. Later, on any chosen event, you can use 
sap.m.semantic.SemanticPage.removeContent(vContent) to remove the original view and sap.m.semantic.SemanticPage.addContent() to add the new View.

[Link to the relevant SAPUI5 Guide Page](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.semantic.SemanticPage.html#addContent)

Hope it helps you.