# How to find loading bottleneck of a slow-loading SAPUI5 app

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm building a custom SAPUI5 app which consists of a seven diagrams (`sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame`) in the page's header content (nested inside a `sap.suite.ui.commons.ChartContainer`) and a grid table (`sap.ui.table.Table`) in the main content area. The data for the charts and the table is provided by an OData V2 Service and the app is running stand-alone on the latest version (1.81.0).

The problem is the long loading time of the app. It takes between 7 and 20 seconds. Is this common for a "more complex" app? I tried to find the bottleneck but everything looks fine. Many network requests are cached (they take 0ms), however, there is a slight delay in between them and I can't see why. Additionally, there is the following warning in the console, although I'm using the `data-sap-async="true"` in my `index.html` file:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. [syncXHRFix-dbg.js:211:15]

#### Code snippets of my index.html and manifest.json

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Loading - Customer Fact Sheet</title>
        <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"com.schott.fiori.customerfactsheet.customerfactsheet-fiori3": "./"}'
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
            data-sap-ui-async="true"
            data-sap-ui-frameOptions="trusted">
        </script>
        <link href="https://www.schott.com/static/assets/gfx/favicon/SCHOTT_16.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" />
    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div data-sap-ui-component data-name="com.schott.fiori.customerfactsheet.customerfactsheet-fiori3" data-id="container" data-settings='{"id" : "customerfactsheet-fiori3"}'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```json
{
    "_version": "1.12.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "com.schott.fiori.customerfactsheet.customerfactsheet-fiori3",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "sourceTemplate": {
            "id": "servicecatalog.connectivityComponentForManifest",
            "version": "0.0.0"
        },
        "dataSources": {
            "YODATA_SD_CFS_MATRIX_SRV": {
                "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/YODATA_SD_CFS_MATRIX_SRV/",
                "type": "OData",
                "settings": {
                    "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        "technology": "UI5",
        "icons": {
            "icon": "",
            "favIcon": "",
            "phone": "",
            "phone@2": "",
            "tablet": "",
            "tablet@2": ""
        },
        "deviceTypes": {
            "desktop": true,
            "tablet": true,
            "phone": true
        }
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "flexEnabled": false,
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "com.schott.fiori.customerfactsheet.customerfactsheet-fiori3.view.Main",
            "type": "XML",
            "async": true,
            "id": "Main"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.65.6",
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.layout": {},
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.m": {}
            }
        },
        "contentDensities": {
            "compact": true,
            "cozy": false
        },
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "com.schott.fiori.customerfactsheet.customerfactsheet-fiori3.i18n.i18n"
                }
            },
            "": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
                "settings": {
                    "defaultOperationMode": "Client",
                    "defaultBindingMode": "OneWay",
                    "defaultCountMode": "Request"
                },
                "dataSource": "YODATA_SD_CFS_MATRIX_SRV",
                "preload": true
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "css": [{
                "uri": "css/style.css"
            }]
        },
        "routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "async": true,
                "viewPath": "com.schott.fiori.customerfactsheet.customerfactsheet-fiori3.view",
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "controlId": "app",
                "clearControlAggregation": false
            },
            "routes": [{
                "name": "RouteMain",
                "pattern": "RouteMain",
                "target": ["TargetMain"]
            }],
            "targets": {
                "TargetMain": {
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "transition": "slide",
                    "clearControlAggregation": false,
                    "viewId": "Main",
                    "viewName": "Main"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sap.platform.hcp": {
        "uri": "webapp",
        "_version": "1.1.0"
    }
}
```

#### Screenshots of my network tab

[image: Network 1]

[image: Network 2]

[image: Network 3]

[image: Network 4]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the Network tab shows, there are many modules loading sequentially one by one and many of them even via sync XHR. The most important task is to **avoid use of sync XHRs.**

- Ensure that no debug mode, `sap-ui-debug`, `sap-ui-xx-componentPreload` or `sap-ui-xx-libraryPreloadFiles` is active unnecessarily.
- Ensure that asynchronous module loading is active:

  - In a *central Fiori launchpad* ("Work Zone") scenario: refer to **[How to make UI5 content compatible with the FLP setting "Asynchronous Module Loading" and CSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74959323/5846045)**
  - If you can control the bootstrap config, ensure that the initial HTML document of the launchpad or app contains the attribute `data-sap-ui-async="true"` in the bootstrap script (`id="sap-ui-bootstrap"`).
- I see in the `manifest.json` that only a small number of libraries are declared. According to the Network tab, however, the app uses controls from other libs which aren't declared in the  `dependencies`. Refer to **[How to avoid loading UI5 controls as single modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49817459/5846045)** for the resolution.
- **Do not use deprecated APIs**; especially those known to send sync XHRs such as `jQuery.sap.require`, `oCore.createComponent`, `sap.ui.*fragment`, `sap.ui.*view`, `sap.ushell.Container.getService`, `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel`, etc.. Make use of the [UI5 linter](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-linter).
- For standalone apps: preload the third party JS files, that are **not** part of the app bundle or library bundle, asynchronously beforehand. If you inspect the *Initiator* column within the Network tab, you can detect more modules that are loaded via sync XHR. Adding those modules to the `data-sap-ui-modules` should avoid it:

  ```html
  <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
     src="..."
     data-sap-ui-modules="sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs,sap/ui/thirdparty/require"
     data-sap-ui-...="..."
  ></script>
  ```

  <sup>The `sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs` is required by `v2.ODataModel`. The `sap/ui/thirdparty/require` module by the `sap.viz` library. Both modules are usually fetched via `loadSyncXHR`. The above snippet fixes it. You might find more such modules.</sup>

Overall, the above points should should already improve the initial loading time noticeably. For more performance guidelines, go through the [Performance Checklist](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/9c6400eb7dc145b78e94a81e6e390780) and other [**Best Practices** for Developers](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/28fcd55b04654977b63dacbee0552712).

---

### Other things to consider

#### I18n

In order to reduce the number of requests consider dropping the i18n-support altogether **if** the app targets only a certain group of people speaking the same language. Multiple requests for i18n text bundles are expensive and may cause synchronous XHRs if not configured correctly. There *is* a way to load the i18n resources asynchronously and also specifying which locales the app supports, but that's for another topic.

#### OData Model

- Do not use `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel` which uses sync XHR to fetch $metadata.
- Consider setting the `countMode` to `"None"` in aggregation binding infos where the `$count` is not really needed since the `$count` calculations tend to be costly in backend.
- The `defaultOperationMode` is set to `"Client"` in your case which fetches all entities at once and slowing down the initial app load. Instead, make use of [lazy loading app contents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799046/5846045), `$filter` queries, the `growing` feature in `sap.m.ListBase` controls, and `sap.ui.table.Table` controls if applicable. Refer to ["Tables: Which One Should I Choose?"](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/148892ff9aea4a18b912829791e38f3e)
- Request `$metadata` and annotation as early as possible by adding `preload: true` to the `/sap.ui5/models/<model name>/` section.

  ```json
  "": {
    "dataSource": "MyV2Source",
    "settings": {
      "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
      "preliminaryContext": true
    },
    "preload": true
  }
  ```

#### UI5 Tooling

[Build the app bundle via UI5 Tooling](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-sample-app#building) which reduces the number of server requests and, in case of a self-contained build, the application size as well.

Comment: very intresting, I personally never considered ruling out the countMode for my aggregation bindings.

Comment: Nice details answer, going to bookmark it for future reference.