# SAPUI5 - How to change the table in the same View?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

situation:

- 2 diferent tables, 1 view;

want to achieve:

- I've got to change the table when I change the selectedKey in a select.

I already tried to create fragments with each table and call the one I want when I change the select.

fragment1 - table 1
fragment2 - table 2

select - oEvent (onChangeSelect) - getSelectedKey - if(key === 1) - call fragment1, if(key === 2) - call fragment2, but it gives me an error.

I don't know if this is correct and I'm not finding any infos related online.
If someone can show some links or give me just an idea on how can I do this, it would be perfect.

Comment: You could also wrap the tables in views and leverage `sap.uxap.BlockBase` so that the 2nd table and data are loaded on-demand. See https://embed.plnkr.co/9ZVwpP?show=block%2FMyBlock.js,view%2FHome.view.xml,preview from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799046/5846045).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the concept of binding to achieve this without coding. assume you have something like that in your view:

```xml
<Select><!-- ... --></Select>
<core:Fragment ... /><!-- table 1 -->
<core:Fragment ... /><!-- table 2 -->
```

First, add a model to your app, which will contain the information about the status of the app (which of the fragments is visible currently). Easiest way is to start with an empty JSON model. If you are familiar with `manifest.json` config, add it there. if not, you could add this in your Components `init` method:

```js
this.setModel(new JSONModel(), "config");
```

This way, the new empty model is available under the name `"config"` in all the views of the app.

Now, we will add a visibility flag, which will control the visibility of your fragments (tables), and can be changed by the select:

```xml
<Select selectedKey="{config>/selectedFragmentKey}">
  <core:Item key=""              text="Please choose one" />
  <core:Item key="showFragment1" text="Show Fragment 1"   />
  <core:Item key="showFragment2" text="Show Fragment 2"   />
</Select>
```

This new version will store the key of the selected item in the config model in the path `/selectedFragment`. Add visibility flag to fragments (tables):

```xml
<!-- table 1 is only visible if "Show Fragment 1" was selected -->
<Table visible="{= ${config>/selectedFragmentKey} === 'showFragment1'}" .../>
<!-- table 2 is only visible if "Show Fragment 2" was selected -->
<Table visible="{= ${config>/selectedFragmentKey} === 'showFragment2'}" .../>
```

and you're done.

Main lesson here: learn to use bindings.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you have a selection control (which has 2 entries), and a table in the view. Based on the selection item, you want to display ONE of the tables at any given point of time. I am also assuming here, that the tables are purely used in the current view only & not really a "re-useable" thing - which gets used in different places of the app (which then renders the use of fragments an overkill).

I am assuming, both tables are bound (although to different data sets).

In that case, consider using the "visible" property of the appropriate table to "false".

Remember - all UI components, including tables inherit from sap.ui.core.Control - which has the "visible" property.

In API reference for table : https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table%23methods/Summary

If you scroll down to "Borrowed from:" section, you will see the "setVisible" and "getVisibe" methods.

So, in the event fired during selection change, you can grab the table control & set the visibility using the aforementioned methods.

Alternatively, you can also set an expression binding directly on the table control in XML, which evaluates to "true" or "false" (perhaps using a formatter).

Let me know if you need further info on this.

Best Regards,
Gopal Nair.