# How to implement an editing mode in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I'm currently building a dynamic table within a sapui5 application. Therefore I'm implementing an editing mode, which is triggered through the click of a button. To change the table cells between view- and edit mode, I defined the following cells:

```
<items>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <cells>
      <Text text="{Name}" visible="{= !${/editMode}}"/>
      <Input value="{Name}" visible="{= ${/editMode}}" change="onChangeName"/>
      <Text .../>
      <Input .../>
          ...
    </cells>
  </ColumnListItem>
</items>
```

Unfortunately, my code does not work as intended. For example, instead of column 1 switching between the "Text" and "Input" nodes, the text node is displayed in one column and the input node in the following column. How do I get the two nodes in the same column?

**View mode** (Text text...)

[image]

**Edit mode** (Input value...)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch views on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644485/how-to-switch-views-on-demand)

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799046/5846045 might help in switching to an "edit" view/section/block generally. See the section "Via Blocks".

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann Thanks for your comment! You mean I should build a block for the "view mode" and one for the "edit mode"?

Comment: Exactly, try it and let me know how it went

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using SAPUI5's `<HBox>` tag ([Click here for documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.m.HBox))
The code now looks like that:

```
<items>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <cells>
      <HBox>
        <Text text="{Name}" visible="{= !${/editMode}}"/>
        <Input value="{Name}" visible="{= ${/editMode}}" change="onChangeName"/>
      </HBox>
      <HBox>
        <Text .../>
        <Input .../>
      </HBox>
          ...
    </cells>
  </ColumnListItem>
</items>
```